# Ripple effect on buttons not working when using @react-native-community/blur in other component

Tags: android, react-native, expo, blur, ripple

Even if BlurView has a height of 100px or 100% in the navbar, it still occupies the entire screen. Visually, you can solve it by adding overflow: hidden to the parent element, but BlurView still interferes with other elements. Ripple Effect whether in buttons or TouchableRipple from rn Paper does not work when BlurView is rendered.

In the example in the image below, the navbar is a separate component and BlurView is rendered there. Despite this, the ripple effect on the button does not work, the button operation itself works without onPress type changes

[image]